# Value Relation not working in custom UI form

Tags: qgis, qt-designer, user-interface

I have an issue similar to the one here below, that was never answered it seems : [QGIS 3 Value Relation current_value() not working in custom ui form](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318611/qgis-3-value-relation-current-value-not-working-in-custom-ui-form/433645#433645)

Daniel on the question above described the issue perfectly so I will copy/paste his description :

I have a custom UI form made with QtDesigner with a couple of drop-down list. I use a Value Relation on those fields to filter the displayed data. The problem is the function `current_value()` is not working when I use a provided UI file, but it works perfectly when I use the default autogenerated form.

My issue is the same,I filter a list based on what is selected on another list.

In the autogenerated form the filtering works perfectly, but if I use a form created with QT designer,the list is not filtered and will show the entire table content.

Any idea on how to fix it?